# Unable to bind a function to event in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

After binding a function once and then unbinding it, I cannot bind it again later to the same function when later needed. I saw it works fine when I do not use '+' the binding function (I'm using bind_all incase it makes any difference). But when I use '+', it does bind it again...

IDLE:

```
    >>> def Released(evnt):
            print(evnt.keysym, ' Removed')
    >>> funcid = _Win.bind_all("<KeyRelease>", Released, '+')
```

I hit some keys and on releasing I got the print statement in Released()

```
    >>> _Win.unbind("<KeyRelease>", funcid)
    >>> funcid = _Win.bind_all("<KeyRelease>", Released, '+')
```

I hit some keys but no output came. But there were no errors either.

So how do I fix this issue?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one answered, I thought a bit more and I came to a workaround to the problem of unbinding... Its not a solution but a workaround...

```
class FunctionManager:
    def __init__(self, funcs = []):
        self.funcs = list(funcs)
    def __call__(self, evnt):
        for func in self.funcs:
            func(evnt)
    def add(self, func):
        self.funcs.append(func)
    def remove(self, func):
        self.funcs.remove(func)
```

So now instead of binding and unbinding function, which didn't work for me, I will just bind an instance of this class containing all required functions and remove functions from it later when required...